# Algebra Word Problem - Minimization of Cost

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The area of a region was 125,000 square feet. A type of fencing costing \$20 per foot was used along the back and front, and a less expensive fence costing \$10 was used for the other sides. What were the dimensions of the region that minimized the cost of the fence?

I am not sure where to start with this question, my class has not done anything like this before.I started the equation with the function
$$
C=20(2x)+10(2y)
$$
And then I used substitution to get
$$
C=40x+2500000/x
$$
I am not sure how to solve this problem. I looked up an example problem similar; however, they used calculus to solve this and I am only in algebra. Does anyone know how to solve this without calculus?

Comment: You probably noticed that dollar signs in a post do weird things.  That is because it is used to initiate inline math mode for [MathJax and $\LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  If you want a dollar sign to appear normally like \$, write it as `\$` with the escape character \.

Comment: **Hint:** use AM-GM.

Comment: @ConnorHarris What's AM-GM?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: @ConnorHarris We've never done something like that before. How would you set it up?

Comment: Note that $Ax + \frac{B}{x} \geq 2 \sqrt{AB}$ with equality iff $Ax = \frac{B}{x}$.